# How to simplify a set identity

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For all sets $A$, $B$ and $C$, $((A \cap (B \cup C)) \cap (A-B)) \cap (B\cup C^c) $

When simplifying, I get 
$((A \cap(B \cup C)) \cap (A \cap B^c)) \cap (B \cup C^c)$

Don't really know what else I can do.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? You can play around all day and find other equivalent forms. but unless you have a clear goal in mind (or, what is really the same, a precise description of "simpler") you will just run around in circles.

Comment: I think that after simplifying we get the empty set...

Comment: What you have there seems to be neither an equation nor an identity: There is no equals sign.

Answer (score 2):

First you use that $\cap$ is commutative. Then, notice that $(B \cup C) \cap (B \cup C^c) = B$. You get $(A \cap B \cap B^c) = \emptyset$.